# Разница метода append

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть код на `jquery`.

```
$('#messages').append($('<li>').text(`${data.username}: ${data.message}`));
```

Я хочу перейти на `js`.

```
const messages = document.getElementById('messages');
messages.append(document.getElementsByTagName('li').text(`${data.username}: ${data.message}`));
```

Я получаю ошибку

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).text is not a function
```

Какая разница метода append в `jquery` и `js`? Что не так я сделал?

Comment: почему вы взяли что проблема в `append`? Вот серьезно, давайте прочитаем ошибку, там есть слово `append`?

Comment: `$('<li>')` не ищет элемент, а создает его

Comment: @ThisMan я понял свою ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#messages').append($('<li>').text(`${data.username}: ${data.message}`));
```

Вы не совсем правильно перевели `jquery` в нативный `js`.

```
// $('<li>') Тут создается элемент, а не ищется в документе
// Поэтому нужно заменить getElementsByTagName на createElement

const messages = document.getElementById('messages');
const li = document.createElement('li');
// У обычных элементов нет функции text
li.innerText = `${data.username}: ${data.message}`
messages.append(li);
```